# RecyclerView only return the last image with Picasso

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm using Kotlin for an Android app.
But i got a problem I can't resolve. May can you help me.

I'm storing some data in Firebase and I want to return it inside a grid RecyclerView.
Everything works (TextView) but only the last image is showing.
All the other images are white, not empty but just.. White. Every time I add an image in Firebase and return it inside the recyclerview, the previous image is going white and the RecyclerView only return the last one I added.

I think the problem comes from the URL and Picasso but I don't know how to resolve it.

Can you please help me ?

There are the screens, my code, and Firebase :

---

**1 - Screens**

**2 - Fragment with RecyclerView**

**3 - Adapter**

**4 - Dataclass**

**5 - XML**

**6 - Firebase**

---

**1 - Screens :**

Recyclerview (there are 4 images but only we can only see one, the rest are white) :

[image]

The screen of the XML (the src isn't a white image) :

[image]

**2 - Fragment with RecyclerView**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.givenaskv1.R
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_flux.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.post_vente.*

private const val TAG = "TAG"
class Flux : Fragment() {

    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null
    private lateinit var dbref : DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var userRecyclerview : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userArrayList : ArrayList<DataClassArticle>
    private lateinit var articleAdapter: ArticleAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        fun getUserData() {
            dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Vente")
            dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        for (userSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                            val user = userSnapshot.getValue(DataClassArticle::class.java)
                            userArrayList.add(user!!)
                            userRecyclerview.adapter = ArticleAdapter(userArrayList)

                        }
                      //  userRecyclerview.adapter = ArticleAdapter(userArrayList)
                    }
                }
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
            })
        }
        getUserData()
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flux, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(itemView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(itemView, savedInstanceState)
        // RvPosts = le recyclerview
        btnPublierVente.setOnClickListener {
            val bottomSheet = BottomsheetVentes()
            bottomSheet.show(fragmentManager!!, "BottomSheet")
        }

        rvPosts.apply {
            userRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.rvPosts)
            // articleAdapter = ArticleAdapter(context.applicationContext)
            userRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
            //  recyclerView.adapter = articleAdapter
            userArrayList = arrayListOf<DataClassArticle>()
            // dataList = emptyList<DataClassArticle>()

            // set a LinearLayoutManager to handle Android
            // RecyclerView behavior
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
//            articleAdapter.setDataList(userArrayList)
            rvPosts.setLayoutManager(GridLayoutManager(this.context, 2))

        }
    }
}
```

**3 - Adapter**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.givenaskv1.R
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class ArticleAdapter(private var articleList: ArrayList<DataClassArticle>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    val TAG = "TAG"
    var dataList = emptyList<DataClassArticle>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.post_vente, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    internal fun setDataList(dataList : List<DataClassArticle>) {
        this.dataList = dataList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val data = articleList[position]

        val targetImageView = holder.articleImage
        Picasso.get().load(data.photo).into(targetImageView)
        
        holder.articleTitle.text = data.titrevente
        holder.articlePrice.text = data.prixvente
        holder.articleLocalisation.text = data.zone
        holder.articleId.text = data.venteId
        holder.venteUser.text = data.firstname
        
    }
    override fun getItemCount() : Int {
        return articleList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var articleImage : ImageView
        var articleTitle : TextView
        var articlePrice : TextView
        var articleLocalisation : TextView
        var venteUser : TextView
        var articleId : TextView
        var photoUrl : TextView

        init {
            articleImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.articleImage)
            articleTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titreArticle)
            articlePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.prixArticle)
            articleLocalisation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomVilleArticle)
            venteUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.venteUser)
            articleId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.venteId)
            photoUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoUrl)

            
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val context = itemView.context
                val intent = Intent(context, DescriptionVente::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("USER_KEY_VENTE", articleId.text)
                    putExtra("USER_KEY_FIRSTNAME", venteUser.text )
                    putExtra("USER_KEY_FIRSTNAME", venteUser.text )
                }
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**4 - Dataclass**

```
data class DataClassArticle(
    var titrevente: String? = null,
    var prixvente: String? = null,
    var zone: String? = null,
    var venteId : String? = null,
    var firstname : String? = null,
    var photo: String? = null,
    var photoUrl : String? = null
)
```

**5 - XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/articleImage"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/RoundedSquare"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titreArticle"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
            android:text="Titre de l'article"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/saveicone"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prixArticle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenir45"
            android:text="20"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/avenir45"
            android:text="€"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomVilleArticle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text="Nom de la ville"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateAericle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text="3 j"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/venteId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/venteUser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/photoUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</GridLayout>
```

**6 - Firebase**

The photo2, photo3, photo4 are vollontary null because I did'nt upload any image. I dont return photo2, photo3, photo4 inside the code.

[image]

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: I would suggest at first setting the adapter only once, ideally in your `onViewCreated`  and not on each item that is read from Firebase connection. https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview might give you an idea, specifically the `Notifying the Adapter` section

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.